# Check whether a symbol can be safely evaluated

Tags: julia

I have a string `x`. I think that `x` is a string representation of a type that is a subtype of `Number`. For example, `x` might take the value `"Float64"`. I could check this using:

```
eval(parse(x)) <: Number
```

However, it is possible that `x` contains something dangerous, like some variant on `"rm(something_important)"`, so using `eval` is a bad idea until I'm sure `x` is safe.

Is there any way I can safely check whether `x` is a string representation of a subtype of `Number`?

(other than building an array of strings of all possible sub-types of `Number` and comparing...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl) package has to deal with this.  [It tackles it](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl/blob/76e0265faec79ca5d11b8fb0678169c132fd322e/src/JLD.jl#L834-L842) by parsing the string and then inspecting the result *before* `eval`ing it.  If the parsed string is what it considers to be a [`valid_type_expression`](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl/blob/76e0265faec79ca5d11b8fb0678169c132fd322e/src/JLD.jl#L761-L765) then it knows that it should be safe to evaluate in the `Main` namespace.  This allows it to pickup custom types from the Main namespace that wouldn't be available from within a `baremodule`.

---

More details: After you parse an arbitrary string, you can inspect the returned object to see if it's "safe" to evaluate:

```
julia> dump(parse("Int"))
Symbol Int

julia> dump(parse("Vector{Int}"))
Expr
  head: Symbol curly
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Symbol Vector
    2: Symbol Int
  typ: Any

julia> dump(parse("""rm("/")"""))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Symbol rm
    2: ASCIIString "/"
  typ: Any
```

We want to ensure that we never `eval` an expression that could call arbitrary behaviors.  Depending on how thoroughly you want to support the type syntax, your solution could be quite simple or it could be as complicated as the HDF5 solution I linked above.  If you're just after simple, unparameterized types we can simplify things substantially:

```
is_valid_type_expression(ex::Symbol) = true
is_valid_type_expression(ex) = false

function julia_type(string)
    ex = parse(string)
    if is_valid_type_expression(ex)
        try
            typ = eval(Main, ex)
            isa(typ, Type) && typ <: Number && return typ
        end
    end
    error("unsupported type: $string")
end

julia> julia_type("String")
ERROR: unsupported type: String
 in julia_type at none:9

julia> julia_type("Int")
Int64

julia> julia_type("""rm("/")""")
ERROR: unsupported type: rm("/")
 in julia_type at none:9
```

Note that anything more complicated than a symbol isn't allowed to be `eval`'ed.  And after `eval`ing the expression, we check to ensure that the type is a Type and that it's a subtype of `Number`.  This will also allow custom subtypes of `Number` in addition to the builtin ones, since we're evaluating it in the `Main` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm afraid I don't really understand the solution. The linked function `is_valid_type_ex` looks like it will return `true` regardless of whether the input is `Expr(parse("Float64"))` or `Expr(parse("HelloWorld"))`. My meta-programming skills are essentially non-existant, so this is almost certainly the source of the problem. Is there any chance you could go into a bit more detail in your answer? Apologies, and thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing. See my update.  I used similar function names and setup to the HDF5 code, so you can see how I simplified things if you ever want to support more complicated type strings.

Comment: Ah. That all makes sense. Many thanks. I have one more question if you don't mind. Your update seems to imply that pretty much any `Symbol` is safe to evaluate, since a dangerous expression will be of type `Expr`. What would happen if I called `eval(symbol("""rm("/")"""))`?

Comment: Symbols are just a name for some location in memory.  When you evaluate it, you load that location if it's defined.  Julia doesn't care how any symbol is spelled.  `eval(symbol("""rm("/")"""))` is simply a undefined variable error.  Well, unless you define it: `eval(:($(symbol("""rm("/")""")) = "Hello world!"))`.  Now evaling it will return the string.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense too. I think my next read-through of the meta-programming section of the docs will go much better after reading your explanations here. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This solution is not safe. Read the comments. I leave it because it is still instructive.

`eval` optionally takes a module as its first argument.

You could evaluate it in a bare module (`baremodule`), so the command doesn't have access to the standard library (then it cannot do much harm).

```
julia> baremodule M
       end

julia> x = :(rm("/"))
:(rm("/"))

julia> eval(M, x)
ERROR: rm not defined

julia> x = :"Float64"
"Float64"

julia> eval(M, x)
"Float64"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are sneaky ways to break out of the `baremodule`.  `eval(M, :(Core.Inference.println("FOOEY")))`.

Comment: Even simpler: `eval(M, :(Main.Base.println("I have access to all functions")))`

Comment: Thanks for responding. A shame it wasn't this simple :-)