# Parse 2D-Array in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia I can create 2D-arrays with

```
[1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8]
2×4 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

The problem is, that I need to parse a 2D-array supplied as an argument to a script - that is as a String.

For example

```
$ julia script.jl "[1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8]"
```

and in the script something like:

```
c = parse.(ARGS[1])
```

and c should be a 2×4 array.

I am flexible regarding the format of the input String.

The usecase is, that I want to call an optimization problem implemented in Julia + JuMP from within Java.

Comment: you mean `c = eval(parse(ARGS[1]))` ... but not sure that's the best way to do such a thing

Comment: also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194951/what-is-the-equivalent-of-pythons-ast-literal-eval-in-julia which addresses a similar problem (with references to the potential hazards of using `eval`)

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth telling us what it is you're trying to achieve by this, just to make sure this isn't a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). For instance, your problem may be solved very easily by doing something like this `julia -E "c = [1 2 3 4;2 3 4 5]; include(\"script.jl\")"` (or `-ie` instead of `-E` if you wanted to remain in the REPL) (not that this is safer, but ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [`readdlm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/) function, which will allow you to parse the text received from `ARGS` as an array:

```
using DelimitedFiles
a = readdlm(IOBuffer(ARGS[1]),',',';')
display(a)
```

Running:

```
$ julia argscript.jl "1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8"
2×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

You can force the array element type in the script:

```
a = readdlm(IOBuffer(ARGS[1]),',',Int,';')
```

You could even enforce the matrix dimensions by passing two more arguments:

```
using DelimitedFiles
n = parse(Int,ARGS[1])
m = parse(Int,ARGS[2])
a = readdlm(IOBuffer(ARGS[3]),',',Int,';',dims=(n,m))
```

Running:

```
$ julia argscript.jl 2 3 "3,2,1;2,6,8"
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  2  1
 2  6  8

$ julia argscript.jl 2 4 "3,2,1;2,6,8"
ERROR: LoadError: at row 2, column 1 : ErrorException("missing value at row 1 column 4"))
```